# How to findAll by a specific variable in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I have the following MongoDB collection of bets:

```
{
        id: String,
        user_id: String,
        type: String,
        events: [{
            eventID: String,
            sport: String,
            evento: String,
            aposta: String,
            estado: String,
            odd: String
        }],
        total_odd: String,
        bet_ammount: String,
        state: String,
        date: String
  }
```

My goal is to send an HTTP request into /bet and reply with all the bets in my Database that correspond to the given "user_id" that is sent in the initial request.

For example, if there were 3 bets that had the user_id with "61e0eb548714ee662c2d76d1", I would want to to send all 3 bets in the body of the reply. I've had a similar request where I would only need to send a specific bet according to it's ID. The code for that is the following:

```
router.get('/bet', (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers.token;
  jwt.verify(token, 'secretkey', (error, decoded) =>{
    if (error) return res.status(401).json({
      title: 'Unauthorized'
    })
    BetModel.findOne({ user_id: decoded.userId }, (error, bet) => {
      if (error) return console.log(error)
      return res.status(200).json({
        title: 'Bets Grabbed',
        bet:{
          _id: bet._id,
          events: bet.events,
          total_odd: bet.total_odd,
          bet_amount: bet.bet_amount,
          state: bet.state,
          date: bet.date,
          user_id: bet.user_id
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

How could I change this to initially get every bet for that specific user_id and then send them all in the HTTP reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another route that changes the `findOne` query to `find`, and sends the result to the HTTP reply.

```js
BetModel.find({ user_id: decoded.userId }, (error, bets) => {
     if (error) return console.log(error)
     return res.status(200).json({
          title: 'Bets Grabbed',
          bets: bets
     })
})
```

You could then iterate through each of the bets on the frontend.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I tried that but I wasn't getting the bets on the frontend for some reason... Must have typed something wrong and wasn't being able to get there.